# How do I rename a folder/directory in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory

Let:
Folder to rename
c:\temp\Torename
to:
c:\temp\ToRename

Directory.Move does not work because the folder(:\temp\Torename) already exist.

I am looking for a solution that does not involve creating a temp folder.
I have this solution in place:
Move to a temp folder (unique name) eg c:\temp\TorenameTemp
Move from temp folder to new folder. eg c:\temp\ToRename
The problem is that my folder can get very big and move can take some time to execute. I like windows explorer solution in which user renames on the spot regardless of size.

thanks for yor time.

Comment: You're trying to change the case of an existing folder?

Comment: Would it be easier to create the directory with the correct name in the first place?

Comment: SLaks: Yes
Mark: Yes- I would love to, but we do not have control over the user and the information is being saved on disk, that is reason that I need to solve this issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Directory.Move(@"C:\Temp\Dir1", @"C:\Temp\dir1_temp");
Directory.Move(@"C:\Temp\dir1_temp", @"C:\Temp\dir1");
```

The files won't be moved unless you are moving them to a different volume.  If destination is on the same volume, only the name of directory will change.

Comment: This solution will be used against a network drive.
(\\server\MyShare\dir1)

Comment: As long as the volume is the same, you will be fine.

Answer (score 4):

`Directory.Move` doesn't scale with the directory size (unless you're copying to a different drive), so there's nothing wrong with calling it twice.

Answer (score 2):

**2020 Solution:** Here's my method to rename a directory safely.

```
/// <summary>
/// Renames a folder name
/// </summary>
/// <param name="directory">The full directory of the folder</param>
/// <param name="newFolderName">New name of the folder</param>
/// <returns>Returns true if rename is successfull</returns>
public static bool RenameFolder(string directory, string newFolderName)
{
    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(directory) ||
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newFolderName))
        {
            return false;
        }


        var oldDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(directory);

        if (!oldDirectory.Exists)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (string.Equals(oldDirectory.Name, newFolderName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            //new folder name is the same with the old one.
            return false;
        }

        string newDirectory;

        if (oldDirectory.Parent == null)
        {
            //root directory
            newDirectory = Path.Combine(directory, newFolderName);
        }
        else
        {
            newDirectory = Path.Combine(oldDirectory.Parent.FullName, newFolderName);
        }

        if (Directory.Exists(newDirectory))
        {
            //target directory already exists
            return false;
        }

        oldDirectory.MoveTo(newDirectory);

        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        //ignored
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: From my tests, if oldDirectory.Parent == null, I would just set newDirectory to newFolderName.  It is only null if it is, ie "C:\\" and newFolderName would be a different drive.  A child folder of "C:\\" will have a .Parent of "C:\\" and would fall into the second logic branch, which needs the Path.Combine method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it could be done:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameDirectory("c:\temp\Torename", "ToRename")
```

The first parameter is the current directory, the second parameter is the new name of the directory.

Source: [FileSystem.RenameDirectory Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.renamedirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This sample is in VB.NET. C# naturally has no namespace for "My" and unfortunately no alternative to it. You would have to add the Microsoft.VisualBasic reference in your project and import the FileIO namespace under it into the class in which you wish to use the equivalent statement, "FileSystem.RenameDirectory("c:\temp\Torename", "ToRename");". Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

After looking around for a complete solution, I wrapped everyone's advice/concerns into this utility method.

You can call it with a simple:

```
DirectoryHelper.RenameDirectory(@"C:\temp\RenameMe\", "RenameMeToThis");
```

Provided in the RenameDirectory method is a full-blowout of all possible exceptions, according to what I found in MSDN documentation.  You may choose to simplify them down to a single try-catch block (possible, not recommended), or you may wish to modify how exceptions are handled, but this should get you going.  I've also included a third, optional, parameter that allows you to suppress exceptions if you want to, which would just return a false instead of throwing an exception.  It is defaulted to false (ie, doesn't suppress exceptions).

I have not tried out each path to test, but I would be VERY careful about renaming a drive, such as "C:\" to "E:\".  It would probably throw an exception... but I've not tested.  :-)

Overall, just copy/paste this solution and maybe remove some comments/links to research and it will work.

```
   public class DirectoryHelper
    {
        public static bool RenameDirectory(string sourceDirectoryPath, string newDirectoryNameWithNoPath, bool suppressExceptions = false)
        {
            try
            {
                DirectoryInfo di;
                try
                {
                    //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.-ctor?view=net-5.0
                    di = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirectoryPath);
                }
                catch (ArgumentNullException e)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Source directory path is null.", e);
                }
                catch (SecurityException e)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"The caller does not have the required permission for Source Directory:{sourceDirectoryPath}.", e);
                }
                catch (ArgumentException e)
                {
                    //Could reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars?view=net-5.0 
                    throw new Exception($"Source directory path contains invalid character(s): {sourceDirectoryPath}", e);
                }
                catch (PathTooLongException e)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Source directory path is too long. Length={sourceDirectoryPath.Length}", e);
                }

                string destinationDirectoryPath = di.Parent == null ? newDirectoryNameWithNoPath : Path.Combine(di.Parent.FullName, newDirectoryNameWithNoPath);

                try
                {
                    //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.moveto?view=net-5.0 
                    di.MoveTo(destinationDirectoryPath);
                }
                catch (ArgumentNullException e)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Destination directory is null.", e);
                }
                catch (ArgumentException e)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Destination directory must not be empty.", e);
                }
                catch (SecurityException e)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"The caller does not have the required permission for Directory rename:{destinationDirectoryPath}.", e);
                }
                catch (PathTooLongException e)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Rename path is too long. Length={destinationDirectoryPath.Length}", e);
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    if (Directory.Exists(destinationDirectoryPath))
                    {
                        throw new Exception($"Cannot rename source directory, destination directory already exists: {destinationDirectoryPath}", e);
                    }

                    if (string.Equals(sourceDirectoryPath, destinationDirectoryPath, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        throw new Exception($"Source directory cannot be the same as Destination directory.", e);
                    }

                    throw new Exception($"IOException: {e.Message}", e);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                if (!suppressExceptions)
                {
                    throw;
                }

                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Directory.Move for directory
File.Move for file